# Splunk regex filter events only one occurrence of special character

Tags: regex, splunk, splunk-query

I would like to search only events which has single `'/'` . How can I do that. Below is the start of the query

```
index="association" sourcetype="escaplogs"
```

`data.val` field can have the below type of values

```
restV2/138b-68a8-40be-bb03-567d619e/1e46d-a2a2-4ccd-b26d-f41be4edd
restV2/138b-68a8-40be-bb03-567d619e
```

How can I add the `data.val` in the search which has only single `'/'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want only one `/` then you just search for one:

```
| rex field=data.val "(?<val>^[^/]+/[^/]+$)"
| where !isnull(val)
```

How the regex works:

- `(...)` This is the regular expression
- `?<val>` `val` is the name of the field it will be put into
- `^...$` This matches only a whole string
- `[^/]+` This searches for a number of characters larger than one that has no `/`
- `^[^/]+/[^/]+$` This searches for a string with exactly one `/`
- `(?<val>^[^/]+/[^/]+$)` puts the matching part into a field called `val`

Then you use `where` to just only keep fields where `val` is not null

Here is a run-anywhere example:

```
| makeresults count=2
| streamstats count 
| eval data.val = case(
  count=1, "restV2/138b-68a8-40be-bb03-567d619e/1e46d-a2a2-4ccd-b26d-f41be4edd",
  count=2, "restV2/138b-68a8-40be-bb03-567d619e")
| rex field=data.val "(?<val>^[^/]+/[^/]+$)"
| where !isnull(val)
| fields -val
| table _time data.val
```

Answer (score 2):

@[Jerry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2193968/jerry-jeremiah)'s [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76996178/4418) is interesting - I would do something similar:

```
index="association" sourcetype="escaplogs" 
| rex field=data.val max_match=0 "(?<slashes>\/)"
| where isnotnull(slashes) AND mvcount(slashes)<2
<rest of search>
```

This is going to find everything that a) has at least one slash (`isnotnull(slashes)`) in the field `data.val`, and b) throwout everything with more than 1 (`mvcount(slashes)<2`)

Comment: If you aren't confident with regex this is a good answer.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah - I'm quite confident in my regex skills ... but this one's more flexible, too - want to keep stuff with up to 2 slashes? just change the condition to "`<3`" :)

Comment: Sorry.  I wasn't talking about *your* ability - I was talking about the OPs ability.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah - I wasn't sure whom you meant, hence my reply :)